# getting this error while installing adk plug in eclipse

Tags: android, appium

> An error occurred while collecting items to be installed session
>   context was:(profile=epp.package.jee,
>   phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=,
>   action=). Problems downloading artifact:
>   org.eclipse.update.feature,com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.feature,23.0.7.2120684.

Answer (score 1):

Install adt plugin from eclipse market place, follow the below steps

1.Click "Help" Menu.
2.Click "Eclipse Marketplace..." menu item.
3.Enter the name of the plugin you want.
4.Click "Install" when the plugin appears in the Marketplace List.
5.Restart Eclipse.